# Best practices for dynamic functions in R - when a value is a function of itself at an earlier timestep

Tags: r, dynamic, dplyr, self

I have a series of time steps:

```
t <- 1:10
```

I have a starting value:

```
x <- 1
```

I combine them into a data frame:

```
myDF <- data.frame(T = t, X = NA)
```

and some dynamic update such that my value is a function of self at t - 1:

```
myDF$X[1] = x
myDF$x[2:10] = myDF$x[T-1] + (myDF$x[T-1] * (myDF$T - myDF[T-1]))
```

This simple example would yield the following:

```
T   X
1   0.5
2   1
3   2
4   4
5   8
6   16
7   32
8   64
9   128
10  256
```

What is the best way to program this kind of thing in R? I have developed a number of what feel like brute force solutions. I have come close with mutate(), arrange() and lag() in dplyr, but I can only get the first two values to calculate because it does not evaluate iteratively.

Thanks!

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. I know the example above is closed form - hoping for examples or advice on dynamic functions where you cannot know x at time t without first knowing x at time t-1! Thanks

Comment: Looks to me it's `myDF$T[2:10] = 0.5 * cumprod(1 + diff(myDF$T))`

Comment: @psidom.. `diff` of a sequence separated by 1 will just yield 1's. so whatever you have is `cumprod(2,2,2,2,2,2..)`.. which can be expressed as `0.5*2^(T-1)` which is still the same as `2^(T-2)`

Comment: @sarobins can you give a different example of what you need??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need this (with `dplyr`):

```
x <- 0.5
myDF <- data.frame(T = t)
myDF %>% mutate(X = x * cumprod(1 + T - lag(T, default = first(T))))

#    T     X
#1   1   0.5
#2   2   1.0
#3   3   2.0
#4   4   4.0
#5   5   8.0
#6   6  16.0
#7   7  32.0
#8   8  64.0
#9   9 128.0
#10 10 256.0
```

---

*An informal Derivation*:

```
let x = myDF$x
    t = myDF$T

x[i] = x[i-1] + x[i-1] * (T[i] - T[i-1])
     = x[i-1] * (1 + T[i] - T[i-1])
     = x[i-2] * (1 + T[i-1] - T[i-2]) * (1 + T[i] - T[i-1])
     ...
     = x[1] * (1 + T[2] - T[1]) * ... * (1 + T[i] - T[i-1])

# vectorized solution would be
x    = x[1] * cumprod(1 + T - lag(T))
```

Comment: Right - here cumprod() is doing the iteration. I think I can do something similar for a few instances in my model, but I am curious to know if there is a generalization? In other words, what is cumprod() doing in the background? Running a loop? Apply()?

Comment: `cumprod` is surely a for loop but written in a lower level language probably c or c++; It depends on your problem, not all iterative problems can be vectorized;